# Can we build the wrapper to field mapping using the custom metadata for json outbound callout

Tags: apex, callout

```
Public wrapperdataclass{


class ContactWrapper {
        public String comments;
        public String firstName;
        public String email;
        public String country;
        public String mobilePhone;
}
}
```

how to store this contactwrapper fields in CMT if there in future there is new fields to be added how to make dynamic to add fields in CMT that need to be retrieve in class

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). It's important that you provide details on why you're trying to achieve something as well as what you've tried so far. Could you please [edit] your question to add more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do that without resorting to the Metadata API to create the fields in the custom metadata type object. However, because you are using a wrapper, it means that the Apex class will also need to be edited every time a new attribute is added.

So whenever you have to add a new attribute, it is easier for you to create a field in the custom metadata type object while deploying that new version of the class.

And, internally, your code might consist of multiple lines of assignments, like so:

```
// given that you have the two following instances
CmdObj__c cmdt;
WrapperClass cls;

// you can write a list of assignments, like:
cmdt.Field1__c = cls.field1;
cmdt.Field2__c = cls.field2;
// ...
cmdt.FieldX__c = cls.fieldX;
```